# save instance in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a project where I used FragmentTabHost with inner fragment with FragmentTabHost

Main FragmentActivity

```
-FragmentTabHost 
  -TAB 1 - FragmentTabHost 
       -tab 1 Fragment
       -tab 2 Fragment    
  -TAB 2 - Fragment   
  -TAB 3 - FragmentTabHost    
  -TAB 4 - Fragment
```

when I switch tab2 to tab1 in first TAB1 of main FragmentTabHost their instances always rebuild and I call API method, but i just want to show 'old' results.

How can I save instance of this fragments and dont make any additional query to API?

some snips of code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup(context, getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabContent);
        ......

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragment1").setIndicator(viewLeft),
                FragmentTab1.class, new Bundle(0));
```

**UPD1.** I tried to add

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setRetainInstance(Fragment.java:784)

Comment: try adding `setRetainInstance(true);`

Comment: do you add it to `-TAB 1`

Comment: yes, i tried to add it in TAB1 and in tab1 in other case and got the same error result

Comment: no just add to -TAB1 because tab1 is nested fragment.

Comment: =( it not helped. same error

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to rebuild the instance of any tab, just take the response object of API as a global variable & make a check in onCreateView

YourResponseObject yourResponseObject; //this should be global

```
if(YourResponseObject == null){
    // Hit API here
}else
{
     InflateYourData(YourResponseObject)
}
```

you will be able to retain the instance of the tab.